# Crawl with Scrapy using IP address

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

Im trying to crawl the following site 'http://www.mouse.co.il/misc/search-results?a=v&what=events&where=talAviv-merkaz-jerusalem-sharon-haifa-south'

though I have a problem with the server's dns server so it cant seem to find mouse.co.il.

Ive tried alternatively crawl 'http://www.184.50.166.245/misc/search-results?a=v&what=events&where=talAviv-merkaz-jerusalem-sharon-haifa-south'
Instead though im getting this error:

```
ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://www.184.50.166.245/misc/search-results?a=v&what=events&where=talAviv-merkaz-jerusalem-sharon-haifa-south>
```

How can i fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: The first: it's fine, I had no problems accessing it, the second: you can't its not there

Answer (score 0):

I think problem in web server. If you have problem with DNS, best way - use your file hosts and add record for name and ip.